# save information that user writes when submits the form

Tags: php, forms

I have a form and when the user submits the form I want to save information in inputs, for cases where error happen, users dont need to write the information again.

So Im using this method in code below and it works fine, but only for my input type="file" dont works, when I submit the form, the file that the user choose is not saving.

Is necessary some trick in this case of `<input type="file">`?

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

       <label class="line">
            <span class="data">Select an Image:</span>
            <input type="file" class="fileinput" name="thumb" size="60" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['thumb'])) echo $f['thumb'] ?>" />
        </label>

        <label class="line">
            <span class="data">Title:</span>
            <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['title'])) echo $f['title']; ?>" />
        </label>

        <label class="line">
            <span class="data">Content:</span>
            <textarea name="content"  rows="15"><?php if(isset($_POST['content'])) echo htmlspecialchars($f['content']); ?></textarea>
        </label>

           <label class="line">
            <span class="data">Date:</span>
            <input type="text" name="date" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['date'])) echo $f['date']; else echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s'); ?>" />
        </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Insert" name="sendForm"/>

    </form>
```

My code where I Do the upload:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['thumb']['tmp_name']))
{
  $folder   = '../uploads/';
  $year     = date('Y');
  $month    = date('m');
  $img = $_FILES['thumb'];
  $ext = substr($img['name'],-3);
  uploadImage($img['tmp_name'], $f['url'].'.'.$ext, $folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/');

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html

Comment: have you added enctype='multipart/form-data' to form ?

Comment: Yes, but I forget to put here, sorry.

Comment: As the link tramp points to says, you can't do this... if you could, you could reload any file name in the field and effectively have a way to download ANY file you would want. Obviously, that would be a little dangerous.

Comment: please post the PHP code that does the actual uploading

Comment: Are you reading `$_FILE` in stead of `$_POST` in your php code?

Comment: Guns I update my post with the code where I do the upload!

Comment: Tim Dev I didnt understood your question! Can you please explain better?

Comment: tramp thanks for your answer, but that link you gave me is not about my issue...

Comment: _“is not the same of my problem”_ – it _is_, you just have not realized it yet. You __can not__ pre-fill the `value` of an `input type=file` – the user either has to chose the file _again_ if they fill out this form a second time due to errors in first submission, or you have to store the file that was uploaded on the _first_ submission somewhere on your server when you are processing that _first_ submission.

Comment: Ah ok...I get it now, so its not correct doing this, even if it is possible with some trick, is not recommended for security reasons right?